# Beginner to Ruby on Rails..Need help putting together the framework to my application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am practically brand new to working with Ruby on Rails and I am trying to create an application that has 3 tables for one of my classes.
My original plan was to work with a car dealership application.  In this dealership I had my three models Vehicle, Review, and Salesman.  I started to get confused on what I actually wanted my application to do.  My relationships were a Vehicle has_many Salesmen and Salesmen has_and_belongs_to many Vehicles.  I then related my Vehicles has_many reviews and a review belongs_to_vehicle.
Now I am thinking of throwing that idea away and starting fresh.  I'm thinking it maybe would have been better to use a Customer model instead of a Salesman.  I don't really even know what my question is, but would customer make more sense in this application.

Answer (score 2):

When I first started on rails, I used two sites as my main reference points.

I started with this tutorial. It got me to the basic concepts of a MVC framework.

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

This site helped me with any specific tasks I was trying to accomplish.

http://www.railscasts.com

Answer (score 1):

First, think about what your application is supposed to do.

Second, think about how to model this with Rails.

You skipped the first step, and now you obviously have problems in the second step :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to run before you can walk. Rails is/can be very complicated and complex; there things like data modelling, controllers, and views that need to be considered. If you don't have an understanding of how MVC works, object oriented design, and object oriented programming work in genera,  you are going to have very difficult time with this project.

If I were you, I'd start with a blog. Doing a car dealership website is far more advanced than you are ready for at this point. I don't mean that in an insulting, way, just being honest.

Start here: http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/

This should get you going. These tutorials are great and should get you where you need to go. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As someone else who is new to rails (I've been learning rails as a step up from HTML + CSS that I've worked with for a few years): I would strongly recommend working through some guided tutorials, such as Michael Hartl's tutorial here: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book.

It isn't always fun to work through guided tutorials when you would rather be building the app that you have in your head but you need to learn the basics before you can strike out on your own. While working through a tutorial, experiment with the code the tutorials provide, try out some different things and think about ways the concepts you are learning can be applied to your own app idea.

This approach will be much more successful than just trying to figure things out as you go - you have to know the underlying concepts of the rails framework or you're never going to get where you are trying to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very contrived example you could play around with... I've added comments to explain the pieces.

```
# This represents a given car dealer
class Dealer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vehicles
  has_many :salesmen
  has_many :sales

  # Example attributes might be:
  # dealer's name
  # dealer address
  # company etc
end

# The car/truck etc
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dealer
  has_many :sales

  # Example attributes might be:
  # dealer_id (so you know what dealer has the car)
  # make
  # model
  # color etc
end

# The person who's selling
class Salesman < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dealer
  has_many :sales
  has_many :vehicles_sold, :through => :sales

  # Example attributes might be:
  # dealer_id (so you know what dealer he works for)
  # name
  # address
  # employee number
end

# This is the join table/model between a vehicle & salesman.
# Each row represents the sale of a car.
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vehicle
  belongs_to :salesman

  # vehicle_id (so you know which car was sold)
  # salesman_id (so you know who sold the car)
  # sales price
  # date sold
  # etc
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response... I'm going to try and keep this project as simple as possible and I am now thinking about just doing a Dealer, Vehicle, and Review models.  In this case I would have a Dealer has_many:vehicles and has_many:reviews my attributes are dealer name, dealer address, and company.  A Vehicle belongs_to: dealer with my attributes of dealer_id, make, model, and color.  A review belongs_to:dealer with attributes of dealer_id, comments, and rating.In the long run I have to add in a User model so he/she can log on and submit reviews.Does this make sense?